# Translation Workbench doesn't work with Communities

Tags: customer-community, translation-workbench, language

I used the translation workbench to translate from english to spanish my org, but  when I use the Customer Communities, as a final user with Spanish language configuration they only see the translations of standard objects and the rest (custom objects, fields picklist, etc..) remains in english. It only happens with Community users because the Salesforce users do not have problems. What am I doing wrong or what needs to be done in this case?

Comment: Is your customer community uses visualforce for your view ? Or is it standard layout

Comment: It Is mostly standar layouy and I'm using Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce template

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the languages into the community via the community builder. Once enabled, the translations from the translation workbench will start to come through.

[image: You have to add the languages into the community via the community builder]

Comment: I'm using Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce template and a Dev org. Thanks this was helpful but I did it and still have the problem :)

Comment: Don't think this works for Content > Subtitle Text https://imgur.com/a/FdIoJnz